# Sidekiq - delay until 3 days before a variable date - is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, sidekiq

I'm using Ruby on Rails and currently using Sidekiq to delay the sending of an email to a user for 3 days (after a create action) as such:

```
QuickcontactMailer.delay_until(3.days.from_now).reminder(@quickcontact)
```

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to use a variable date instead of "from_now", something like this:

```
QuickcontactMailer.delay_until(3.days.from(@quickcontact.date_required).reminder(@quickcontact)
```

I can't find any information about it, maybe I'm asking to do a bit too much here. Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
QuickcontactMailer.
    delay_until(@quickcontact.date_required + 3.days).
    reminder(@quickcontact)
```

Comment: Typo: `s/-/+/`.

Comment: `puts 'Thank you'`

Comment: I have slightly re-formatted your answer to respect ppl with not-so-wide screens.

Comment: Excellent thanks very much.. Although this brings a new problem... the date_required is a string in the format "01-01-2017", which throws the error "undefined method `+' for "29-01-2017":String". I'm guessing I'll need to convert the string into the required date format? How would I do that? Still learning all of this so appreciate your help!

Comment: Try `Date.parse('29-01-2017')`

Comment: I tried `QuickcontactMailer.delay_until(Date.parse(@quickcontact.date_required) - 3.days).reminder(@quickcontact)`  but get the error `undefined method to_f'  for Thu, 26 Jan 2017:Date`  Any idea? Thanks again

Comment: Any idea on how to solve the error @mudasobwa ? Thanks!

Comment: `Date#+` already adds days. Use: `Date.parse(@quickcontact.date‌​_required) + 3`.

Comment: I tried that as well @mudasobwa but also with the same error.

Comment: It is impossible. The error is induced. Open the console and type `Date.parse('2017-01-13') + 3`, you’ll get this Monday.

Comment: If I run in the console `@quickcontact = Quickcontact.last`, followed by `Date.parse(@quickcontact.date_required) - 3` it converts the string `12-03-2017` to `Thu, 09 Mar 2017` but would it be the delay_until method not accepting it and throwing the `undefined method `to_f' for Thu, 09 Mar 2017:Date` error?

Comment: Btw, why are you storing dates as a string in the db?